Algorithm / equations to position a point just outside or inside the edge of a regular polygon?
Here is a polygon with a dot inside an edge, and a dot outside another edge.

How do you calculate the $x$ and $y$ position of any dot (whether it's inside or outside of the line's edge) positioned along an edge of a regular polygon (ranging from 3 to 20 sides)?

The dot has radius $r$ (like 1 to 20px)
The dot is placed an offset $o$ from the line's edge.
The position is relative to the center of the polygon.
You say where you want the dot to go using a fraction/percent from 0 to 1, along an edge, where edges are numbered from 1-5 (1-n for arbitrary polygon) going like a clock.

I am a novice when it comes to doing these compsci graphics layout trigonometry problems, so if you could explain such that I could just convert the equations directly into JavaScript code, that would be ideal. Then I can begin to see how it would be applied at a practical level.
The "API" I would like to have is:
function calculateDotPosition({
  polygonRadius, // or some size measurement of some sort
  polygonSideCount,
  polygonEdgeNumber,
  polygonEdgePositionRatio, // from 0 to 1
  // gap is negative or positive "normal" 
  // (outward/inward) position change
  // from being on the line, can be 0 to be on the line
  gap,
  dotRadius,
}) {
  // equations...
}

Knowing the math for this, would make it so I can just say "put a 5px radius dot on the 2nd edge of a pentagon, 10px outside the edge line, at the halfway point on the line", sort of thing. And it would calculate where to put the dot. I don't necessarily need the code (as this is a Math SO), but having some math which would be straightforward to translate into a function like above would be very helpful.

ChatGPT gave me this, but it's hard to check if it's correct without knowing the theory.

Does the radius of the dot matter? Typically, we represent the position of a dot by just its centre

@TonyMathew yes radius matters.

Can you give an example where the radius of the dot affects the calculations in determining the position of the dot?

Let $n$ be number of sides, $V_1 \equiv (x_1, y_1)$ be the coordinates of vertex #1, with polygon centre as $(0,0)$. Let $P \equiv (x_p, y_p)$ be the position of the centre of the target point to be determined, with offset $o$ perpendicular to edge $k^* \to (k^{*}+1)$ at a point $\phi$ down the edge.
\begin{gather}
   \theta_k = (k-1)\frac{2 \pi}{n} \\
   V_k = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta_k & \sin \theta_k \\ - \sin \theta_k & \cos \theta_k \end{bmatrix} V_1 \\
   E_k = V_{k+1} - V_{k} \\
   P = V_{k^*} + \phi E_{k^*} + o \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \frac{E_k^*}{||E_k^*||}
\end{gather}
The above is using matrix notation for compactness of expressions. You could implement using matrix-vector operations, or could expand them out to algebraic equations for the $x$ and $y$ coordinates.
